How to Remove unused options under Add Input Languages Tab
I am unable to add to my previous question; hence my questioṇ
I am wondering whether the Unused Options under the Add Input Language appearing under English(United States).  I suspect the "Devanagari  Unicode" may be the probleṃ - the under-dots and over-dots.
HOW TO REMOVE THESE UNUSED OPTIONṢ


they're not enabled or added - so its likely not the source of the problem
